# Creating outlook email with hyperlink through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have a macro which the idea is to create an Outlook email from a textbox that I have in excel.
The problem is when I write a word and put a hyperlink on it, when the email is displayed, the hyperlink is not there.

```
Sub Envio()
Dim endereco, arquivo, destino, assunto, mensagem, nome, copia, anexo As String
Dim row, report As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

anexo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mensagem").Cells(39, 2).Value
assunto = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mensagem").Cells(5, 2).Value
mensagem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mensagem").[TextBox].Text & vbCrLf
copyblind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mensagem").Cells(8, 2).Value


i = 2

destino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails").Cells(i, 1).Value



Do Until destino = ""
nome = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails").Cells(i, 2).Value
copia = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails").Cells(i, 3).Value


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


With outMail

.To = destino
If copia <> "" Then
.CC = copia
Else
.CC = ""
End If
.BCC = copyblind
.Subject = nome & ", " & assunto
.Body = mensagem
If anexo <> "" Then
.Attachments.Add (anexo)
End If
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & mensagem & "<BR><BR>" & _
"</BODY>"




.Display

End With

i = i + 1
destino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails").Cells(i, 1).Value

Set outMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting HTML tags for a link in the body of your email like so:

```
<a href="https://yourhyperlink.com">Your Hyperlink</a>
```

Comment: But I as I am always changing the hyperlink, I would like to have this in a "dinamic" way

Comment: `<a href=somevariable>Your Hyperlink</a>`

Comment: Perhaps in your case it would be more like `"<a href=" & linkVariable & ">Your Hyperlink</a>"`

Comment: I don't understand a lot of html =(, where should i put it?
Many thanks for the help!

Comment: You put it in the body. Your last line of code in the `With outMail` section has the body. It currently shows `.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & mensagem & "<BR><BR>" & _
"</BODY>"`. The `<BODY>` and `</BODY>` tags show the start and end of the email body, respectively. Your message is already in here, currently stored as the `mensagem` variable. `<a>` and `</a>` tags show the start and end of links, respectively. You just need to put the link tags anywhere in between those body tags...wherever you want it to go.

Comment: I'll make it simple:

`MyLink = "http://www.somewhere.com"`

`.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & mensagem & "<BR><BR>" & "<a href=" & MyLink & ">Hyperlink</a>" & _
"</BODY>"`
This site might be useful in helping you understand HTML elements:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp